# How to protect awsconfiguration.json data details in iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I'm using awsconfiguration.json for AWS Cognito for my iOS Application written in swift. But I'm afraid of security that awsconfiguration.json is stored in my local directory. How can I protect this json file against a third man attack?

Answer (score 2):

Please see similar Github Issue https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-ios/issues/1671

The comments talk about

- the file is non-sensitive data, so resources that should be accessed by authenticated users should be configured with the approiate controls. Amplify CLI helps you with this, depending on the resources you are provisioning in AWS.
- there is a way to configure it in-memory via `AWSInfo.configureDefaultAWSInfo(awsConfiguration)`

Answer (score 1):

Configure your AWS dependencies using in-memory configuration instead of the configuration JSON file as suggested by AWS documentation.

Sample code:

```
func buildAuthConfiguration() -> [String:JSONValue] {
    return [
        "awsCognitoAuthPlugin": [
            "IdentityManager": [
                "Default": [:]
            ],
            "Auth": [
                "Default": [
                    "authenticationFlowType": "String"
                ]
            ],
            "CognitoUserPool": [
                "Default": [
                    "PoolId": "String",
                    "AppClientId": "String",
                    "Region": "String"
                ]
            ],
            "CredentialsProvider": [
                "CognitoIdentity": [
                    "Default": [
                        "PoolId": "String",
                        "Region": "String"
                    ]
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
}

func buildAPIConfiguration() -> [String: JSONValue] {
    return [
        "awsAPIPlugin": [
            "apiName" :  [
                "endpoint": "String",
                "endpointType": "String",
                "authorizationType": "String",
                "region": "String"
            ]
        ]
    ]
}

func configureAmplify() {
    let authConf = AuthCategoryConfiguration(plugins: buildAuthConfiguration())
    let apiConf = APICategoryConfiguration(plugins: buildAPIConfiguration())
    let config = AmplifyConfiguration(
        analytics: nil,
        api: apiConf,
        auth: authConf,
        dataStore: nil,
        hub: nil,
        logging: nil,
        predictions: nil,
        storage: nil
    )
    try Amplify.configure(config)
    // Rest of your code
}
```

Source: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-ios/issues/1171#issuecomment-832988756

Answer (score 0):

You can provide data protection to your app files by saving it into file directory

Following documentation can help you to achieve it.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/protecting_the_user_s_privacy/encrypting_your_app_s_files

Comment: saving it into file directory means it protected completely? Is there any way to encrypt awsconfiguration.json?

Answer (score 0):

The fix to add a new constructor has been released in 2.13.6 version of the SDK.

to allow passing a JSONObject containing the configuration from the awsconfiguration.json file. You can store the information in JSONObject in your own security mechanism and provide it at runtime through the constructor.

https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/pull/1002